Why does it snow in Harbin, China but not in Venice, Italy?
Both cities have the same latitude. Why does it snow in Harbin but not in Venice?

Related but different: Why does Japan get so much snow?

Also, your statement isn't exactly true: https://veneziaautentica.com/pictures-venice-snow/  But WeatherSpark suggests Harbin gets 4.3" of snow on average, whereas Venice gets it relatively little (I see 2001, 2005, 2010 and 2018 pop up in Google as years it has snowed), which seems roughly in line with WeatherSpark's suggestion of 0.3 days per year.

harbin is inland and land looses heat faster than the sea,venice is by the sea,this will moderate the temperature so less snow will fall.

Technically, it does snow in Venice, though the amount is considerably less than in cities of similar latitude such as Harbin or Chicago, or for that matter parts of Italy lying farther west. From [https://www.climatestotravel.com]:(https://www.climatestotravel.com/climate/italy/venice#google_vignette)

Snow in Venice is seen almost every year, but is almost never abundant, in fact, the bora [from the north] is originally a dry wind, and generally brings at most light snowfalls, while when it snows in the western Po Valley (see Milan), here, the sirocco [from the south/Adriatic Sea] raises the temperature and brings rainfall.
On average, less than 5 cm (2 in) of snow fall per year. Venice is therefore one of the least snowy cities in northern Italy.

Venice sits on the northern edge of the Adratic Sea, which in winter tends to warm the iverlying air due to heat retention in the body of water. Thus a southerly wibd is warmed by the sea and tends to melt snow into rain (while farther west, where this wind blows over land, precipitation is more likely to remain snowy); while a northerly wind is colder but also relatively dry and thus tending to bring only light precipitation. Thus the combination of high moisture loading with cold temperatures that typically brings heavier snows does not generally obtain in Venice.
The tendency for greater precipitation events in the Northern Hemisphere to emerge from the south is seen elsewhere, as in the Great Lakes region of the United States. Here, winter systems moving in directly from inland Canada ("Alberta clippers") typically bring less than 10 cm snow accumulation; while those that develop around the Texas/Oklahoma Panhandle, drawing moisture from the warm Gulf of Mexico, can bring snowfalls of 30 cm or more even without enhancements from the Lakes.

In brief, China's Harbin experiences significant snowfall, while Italy's Venice does not, mainly due to Harbin's continental climate, higher altitude, and inland location, which lead to colder winters. Venice's coastal location, humid subtropical climate, and the moderating influence of the Adriatic Sea result in milder winters with more rain and less snow.

Harbin, located in northeastern China, lies in the continental climate zone, characterized by cold, dry winters and hot, humid summers. The city's inland position and high latitude contribute to its long, harsh winters with substantial snowfall. Venice, located in northeastern Italy, lies in the subtropical climate zone, influenced by the Mediterranean Sea. This climate typically features milder winters than continental climates, with less frequent and less substantial snowfall.

Being far inland and far from large bodies of water, Harbin experiences more extreme temperature variations. The lack of moderating influence from oceans or seas means that cold air masses from Siberia can dominate during winter, leading to significant snowfall. Venice is located on the coast of the Adriatic Sea, which has a moderating effect on its climate. The sea helps keep winter temperatures milder, reducing the likelihood of snow.

During winter, Harbin is affected by cold air masses from Siberia. These cold air masses can carry moisture, leading to snowfall when encountering other weather systems. The weather patterns influencing Venice in winter are often milder due to the Mediterranean influence. Cold air masses from the north are generally moderated when they reach Venice, leading to less frequent and lighter snowfalls. Precipitation in Venice during winter is more likely to fall as rain rather than snow


Similarly, cities like Delhi, located in the Indo-Gangetic (North Indian) Plain, do not experience significant snowfall. In contrast, Chinese cities, such as Changsha, situated at a similar latitude, experience substantial snowfall. The Himalayas, which act as a wall between the Indian subcontinent and the Tibetan Plateau and block the cold air masses from Siberia, are one of the significant factors behind this.

[+1] if you see an opportunity for an additional answer to Why do 30% of all typhoons in the western north pacific (WNP) affect Taiwan please feel free to add one.

One limitation: Harbin's altitude is listedby Wikipedia as only 150 m, which is lower than for instance Chicago. The altitude difference is not really there, leaving Venice's access to the sea a more decisive factor.

@OscarLanzi, The elevation/altitude of Venice is only 1 m above MSL. It is also a contributing factor, but not so significant. Harbin's comparatively higher altitude, far inland position, and latitude combined play a role in snowfall. The altitude also increases the chances of snowfall.
